# Sudo update-grub does not work (single boot Ubuntu 22.04)

Tags: grub2, kernel

Ubuntu 22.04 KDE 5.15.0-52 Nvidia 470 proprietary.
I see there is a lot of questions on this subject, but all the answers I've read, have not solved the problem. I edit the GRUB, save it, and it keeps the change. When I "sudo update-grub" it doesn't work. It gives me this read out. `Sourcing file /etc/default/grub /usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 1: /etc/default/grub: /#: not found`

-Here is the grub file, I added the lines...  GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved.

```
/# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false
```

I'm trying to boot on Kernel 5.15.0-52 by default. I ignorantly did a full upgrade to 5.15.0-53 and subsequently 5.15.0-56 and now have two unneeded kernels, it will not let me purge or remove them. (errors, unsigned, etc) (Learned Nvidia proprietary and nouveau w kernel upgrades does not work)
This is what I tried that taught me a lot, but the file and script is there. Everything appears to be where it is supposed to be.

The update-grub command was created to make things easier - it is simply a shell script in /usr/sbin/:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
exec grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg "$@"
```

If it is not there, you can make your own. To do that, run this, and paste in the above script:

```
sudo nano /usr/sbin/update-grub
```

Save with Ctrl+O, and exit with Ctrl+X.

Then run these:

```
sudo chown root:root /usr/sbin/update-grub
sudo chmod 755 /usr/sbin/update-grub
```

And you should now be able to run update-grub. :-)

I also ran "sudo update-grub" among other minor things, but still no update-grub.
Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the very first character of the first line in `/ect/default/grub`, the `/`.

The first line should be a comment and therefor start with `#`. Change

```
/# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
```

to

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
```

You should also remove the line

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
```

since you don't want to define GRUB_DEFAULT twice.